# Interpolation of geographical coordinates c++

Tags: c++, c

I'm searching for solution of my problem.

I have some geographical coordinates like this:

```
Lat. 32.5327 Lon. 95.5019   time 15:44:44
Lat. 32.5339 Lon. 96.1439   time 15:48:31
```

It's position of  some object and time when it was in that position.
What i need is to check in some interval of time(30 seconds for example), what was the position of the object between  these points.

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: This seems like a legitimate question, I don't think a simple linear interpolation between the endpoints will be perfectly accurate. But you'll need to go into more detail about what you've tried and why it didn't work or this question is likely to be closed.

Comment: If you want to interpolate over a sphere try [Slerp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp)

Comment: There is no need to be perfectly accurate and i only watch some code and i don't know how combine it with time.

Comment: So your problem is how to interpolate between to time values? Maybe because of the non-decimal time format?

Comment: @MOehm His problem is how to interpolate between spherical coordinates.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: No. I thought so first, too, but he said the inaccuracy of linear interpolation would be fine and he didn't know how to "combine it with time". So that's why I asked.

Comment: 1 was think for a while. if i change time to something like the start time will be 1 and end time will be x and points between them will be next numbers like 2,3. Will it work?

Comment: 1st cut: Consider the earth as flat (flatland) and post code that.  Simply interpolate the `lon` and the `lat` separately.  `lon(t) = (lon2-lon1)/(time2-time1)*(t - time1) + lon1`.  Then consider round earth effects.  As it  stands, OP needs to show some attempt.  Then re-edit post.

Answer (score 1):

Interpolating over a sphere and finding the shortest path between two points would require for example [Slerp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp).

But for distances less than 100km you will end up with a line (more or less) so do not bother and do a linear interpolation.

As @chux pointed out: linear interpolation will exibit significant artifacts when interpolating near the poles.

Comment: Linear interpolation over nearby distances works well as long as 1) not near the poles, 2) not across 180 degree east/west.

Comment: @chux What is the reason to not interpolate "across 180 degree east/west" ?

Comment: @Squeezie `lng1 = -179; lng2 = + 179; same latitudes` With typical interpolation, that results in the half-way longitude of 0 when +/-180 is likely wanted.  Both 0 and 180 are correctly half way from `lng1,lng2`.  Code would need another step: choosing the nearer longitude.  Code gets more complicated with differing latitudes where a mid-point is near the poles.

Comment: @chux That's what I thought. One could fix it by adding a easting or such. But it's not a problem like the Latitudes which gets distorted the more you get closer to the north/east